# JavaScript collision from top and bottom

Tags: javascript, collision

I just need your help now. I've made some collision system which works great on collision from the left and right side. BUT! I don!t know how to make top and bottom. I'd appreciate you help here.

```
function collided(a, b) {
  if((((a['y'] + a['height']) >= b['y']) && ((a['y'] + a['height']) <= b['y'] + b['height'])) && (((a['x'] + a['width']) >= b['x']) && ((a['x'] + a['width']) <= (b['x'] + b['width']))))
    return 1;
  else if(((a['y'] + a['height']) >= (b['y'])) && ((a['y'] + a['height']) <= (b['y'] + b['height'])) && ((a['x'] == (b['x'] + b['width']))))
    return 2;
// i need help with this (top collision) and need some bottom collision
  else if((b['y'] < (a['y'] + a['height'] + 5)) && ((b['x']) < (a['x'] + a['width'])) && ((a['x']) < (b['x'] + b['width'])))
    return 3;
}
```

So **return 1** is collision from left (from the **b** object left, like the staying one), 2 is right, 3 is top and 4 is bottom.

Comment: I think you can do a little mental extrapolation here to figure this one out on your own. It is just a little math. Write down how you would determine this as a human, and then you have the instructions to give the computer.

Comment: I'm stuck here... If I whatever I can, it just fails like: the a object cannot move down all around after b object x trail.

Comment: Something amazing happened now. I decided to rewrite the top collision code and so i removed the old one... and what happened? I wrote the same code again with no sight at the previous one... :(

Comment: Are you assuming that you will check for collision after every single unit of movement?  This seems to be the case when you test for collision from right since you have (a['x'] == (b['x'] + b['width']).  If your a object moves more than one unit, it will pass your collision from right test and be "inside" of b.